# Supress Can't Locate module warning in Perl

Tags: perl

I was implementing logger in the perl backend service. I am trying to print the content trapped by `local $SIG{__DIE__}=`.

```
local $SIG{__DIE__}=
```

catches following error:Can't locate xyz.pm in @INC (@INC contains ...............).

Whenever I run the script by command line, I can't see the above error message generated on the terminal. Just local $SIG{**DIE**}=  catches this message.

Is there any way to supress can't locate warning message?

I tried to go through perl doc(Category Hierarchy) http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html, but i don't know, can't locate warning belongs to which category?

Comment: Warnings and errors are different beasts.

Answer (score 3):

That's an error, not a warning. And you should fix this error, because your script will not run until you install the required module.

If you just don't want to log that specific message, you could just skip anything that matches some regex of uninteresting messages:

```
my $uninteresting_re = qr{\ACan't locate \w+(?:/\w+)*[.]pm in \@INC [(]you may need to install};

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print $log $error unless $error =~ $uninteresting;
    # let error propagation continue as usual
};
```

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that you don't actually need the failing module for your code to work, it's possible to prevent the "Can't locate..." error from being generated at all.  At the beginning of your program (or at least before it tries to load the missing module), add:

```
use PerlIO::scalar;
BEGIN {
  push @INC, sub { open my $fh, "<", \"1"; return $fh };
}
```

This adds an entry to the end of `@INC` which will return an empty dummy file if no actual file is found, so every `use` (or `require`) will *always* find something to load.

It's not a good idea.  It's far, *far* more likely to cover up real problems than to fix anything at all.  But it *can* be done if you really want to take that risk.

Comment: And of course it's always possible within the `sub` to check which module is being loaded, and only return the dummy file if it's known to be an optional module. However, it's probably better to find the `require` or `use` statement which loads the missing module, and wrap it in an `eval {...}` or `try {...}` block.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler is always to start by looking at the value of `$^S`. This tells you whether an `eval{}` is currently running. If it is, you should ignore it.

Any handler must therefore always start

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
  return if $^S;
  ...
};
```